# Are there examples or support for Google Drive API with ColdFusion?

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to access the Google Drive API via ColdFusion (version 9) but I have not found any up to date information to do so. Does anyone know of any information out there regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

Since Google Drive SDK is basically HTTP request and since you can make [http request with ColdFusion](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0693d5dae123bcd28f6d-7ff8.html), you can use Google Drive SDK with ColdFusion. However, there is no official support for ColdFusion in Google Drive, and you should build your own library for it. Here is [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) about Drive API having some details of requests and responses you will have with Drive SDK.

FYI, you can easily test API requests using [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)